# How do I return many inputs taken at different times into excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to create a simple Python script that will collect users' information, to work in tandem with an Arduino relay that is passcode protected in order to use a setup in my lab. I want a python script to collect things such as name, date, time, and purpose of the user, store that information in an excel sheet, then return the Arduino passcode. Here is my script so far:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

print("Welcome to 15's DC setup!")
print("In order to operate, you must enter the following info.")
print("After entering, the Arduino keypad password will appear.")

name = input("Name (first+last): ")
date = input("Date (**:**): ")
time = input("Time(**:**): ")
ampm = input("AM or PM: ")
purpose = input("Purpose of using equipment: ")

print("Thank you! The passcode is: 0000")
    

l1 = [name]
l2 = [date]
l3 = [time + ampm]
l4 = [purpose]

df = DataFrame({'Name': l1, 'Date': l2, 'Time': l3, 'Purpose': l4})

df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\export.xlsx', index = False, header=True)
```

This does what I want it to do, but it is not replicable and it cannot store more than one user's data; it overrides the inputs in r1. Is there a way to do this or should I look other places to accomplish this task?

Comment: So the issue is that it overwrites the previous file when writing to excel, so you end up with only 1 row?

Comment: Yes, it overwrites the first row, and I don't know how to make it so that when it runs again it fills the next row.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas.to_excel()` overwrites any files that share the same name and file type. `export.xlsx` is a brand new file every time. This is an approach you can use to get around this.

```
file_path = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\export.xlsx'

# Try to open 'export.xlsx' as a DataFrame. 
# If it exists then use pd.concat to add the new rows to the existing 
# data and create a new frame (df3). 
# Then write df3 to the directory as a new spreadsheet replacing the old one

try:

    df2 = pd.read_excel(file_path)

    df3 = pd.concat([df, df2])

    df3.to_excel(file_path, index=False, header=True)

# If 'export.xlsx' doesn't currently exist then create it using the current data

except:

    df.to_excel(file_path, index=False, header=True)
```